# Как передать число в другое активити?

Tags: java, android

Как передать среднее арифметическое в другое activity ? При этом ошибка на

" intent.putExtra("average", sum);"

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {

String[] countries = {"Urugay", "Paraguay", "Jamaica", "Peru", "Mexico"};
int[] population = {6770000, 2300000, 500000, 6310000, 7000000};
Button btnSubmit;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Map<String, Integer> countryData = new HashMap<>(countries.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
        countryData.put(countries[i], population[i]);
        }
        countryData.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " -> " + value));

    ListView countriesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.countriesList);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, countries);

            countriesList.setAdapter(adapter);

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < population.length; i++)
    {
        sum += population[i];
    }

    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
    intent.putExtra("average", sum);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
  }
```

Comment: Переменные не достижимы за пределами своей области видимости - выведите `sum` в поле класса. И `.getText().toString()` - это не применимо к типу `int`, уберите.

Comment: Вы в какой программе код пишете? Я не понимаю как вам AndroidStudio могла дать применить к int sum getText() , да еще использовать переменную sum в onClick(), определенную в другом закрытом методе.

Comment: @Danilka37 Там ошибка. Должно " intent.putExtra("average", sum);"

Answer (score 1):

Переменную `sum` определите не в `onCreate()`, а как поле класса сразу после `Button btnSubmit;`. Иначе в `onClick()` она просто не видна.

Comment: @Danilka37Так и сделал. Вопрос, будет ли передавать расчитанное среднее арифметическое ?

Comment: @Ahillesius Вы запустите и проверьте. Я остальной логики вашего приложения не знаю и не могу сказать есть ли там ошибка.